# i want to retrieve selected row data in textboxes in html using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

i have used html table to display data from database using PHP. I have id,client name ,staff name and matter columns in database and i am displaying only client name, staff name and matter columns in the html table.i have three textbox for client name ,staff name, matter .now, i want to display the selected row's data in the three textbox respectively.

```
$(document).ready(function () {      
     $('#tableresult tr').click(function (event) {
          alert(this.id); //trying to alert id of the clicked row          

     });
 });
```

i tried this ,still not working-

```
$('#editclientname').val($(this).attr('client_name'));
```

html markups-

```
<label for="Client Name">Client Name</label><br />
                            <input type="text" id="editclientname" name="editclientname" />
                             </div>

                             <div class="col-md-2">
                             <label for="Staff Name">Staff Name</label><br />
                            <input type="text" id="editstaffname" name="editstaffname" />
                             </div>

                              <div class="col-md-2">
                             <label for="Matter">Matter</label><br />
                            <input type="text" id="editmatter" name="editmatter" />
                             </div>
```

table and php code-

```
 <table class="footable" data-filter="#filter" id="tableresult">
                              <thead>
                                <tr>

                                  <th>Client Name</th>
                                  <th>Staff Name</th>
                                  <th>Matter</th>
                                </tr>
                              </thead>
                              <tbody>
                                <?php 
                                 include_once 'db.php';
                                 $sql = "SELECT * FROM newdata";
                                 $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                                 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):; ?>
                                 <tr>
                                  <td><?php echo $row[2]; ?></td>
                                  <td><?php echo $row[3]; ?></td>
                                  <td><?php echo $row[4]; ?></td>
                                 </tr>
                               <?php endwhile; ?>
                              </tbody>
```

Comment: Please provide codes of what you have tried so far :)

Comment: even after trying this ..i am not getting the id in the alert...it says "undefined"..anyways i dont want to retrieve the id .i want to retrieve the client name,staff name and matter in textboxes

Comment: need to see the markup too. as this should not be guess to answer.

Comment: How can you get `id` with `this`. :D

Comment: Include the HTML - maybe the `tr` doesn't have an `id`?

Comment: At what point does it say "undefined"?  inside the alert? on the console startup/click?

Comment: inside the alert @freedomn-m

Comment: Ok, there's nothing wrong with the code *as supplied* (note: pre-edit).  Your `<tr>` simply does not have an `id` attribute.  Working code: https://jsfiddle.net/x2uotspx/

Comment: ya ..got it @freedomn-m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use `.each()` with the index as parameter as:

```js
    $('#tableresult tr').click(function(event) {
      $('td', this).each(function(i) {
        $('.inputWrapper input').eq(i).val(this.textContent);
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='inputWrapper'>
  <input type='text'>
  <input type='text'>
  <input type='text'>
</div>
<table id='tableresult'>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>bar</td>
    <td>baz</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I doubt it, as i answered as per assumptions but you need to modify it accordingly. and BTW you are welcome.

Comment: how do i update the changes in my database if i made the table cells editable @Jai

Comment: That is another question! better to ask a new one. that would be good because answering that one seems too broad in this case now as you mentioned its editable.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to the answer:

```
$('#tableresult tr').click(function(event) {
  $(this).find("td").each(function(index) {
    $($("input").get(index)).val($(this).text());
  });
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo :D](https://jsfiddle.net/z5e6cq3e/)